# TYPO3 - page IDs change when exporting and importing the pagetree with 'Export to .t3d' - v8

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I've created a pagetree like this:

```
[0]Site
|_[1]Root
..|_[3]Home
..|_[4]Company
..|_[2]Prices
..|_[5]Solutions
..|_[6]News
..|_[7]Contact
..[8]Footer //Folder
....|_[9]Impressum
....|_[10]Terms of Use
....|_[11]Sitemap
```

When I export it with 'Export to .t3d' and embed the data.t3d file into the initialisation folder of a distribution ... move it to the ext folder via ftp and activate it in the extension manager of another site (blank), the page IDs of the pages change:

```
[0]Site
|_[1]Root
..|_[11]Home
..|_[10]Company
..|_[9]Prices
..|_[8]Solutions
..|_[7]News
..|_[6]Contact
..[2]Footer //Folder
....|_[5]Impressum
....|_[4]Terms of Use
....|_[3]Sitemap
```

When I do the same from the second to the third site (blank) ... the page IDs stay the same:

```
[0]Site
|_[1]Root
..|_[11]Home
..|_[10]Company
..|_[9]Prices
..|_[8]Solutions
..|_[7]News
..|_[6]Contact
..[2]Footer //Folder
....|_[5]Impressum
....|_[4]Terms of Use
....|_[3]Sitemap
```

What logic does the 'Export to .t3d' follow for allocating the page IDs? And why do they not stay the same the first time? As a consequence I need to redefine my configuration setups ...

Comment: When you import, you should choose 'Force ALL UIDs values' to get all origin uids, which also will overwrite existing ones

Comment: Ah ok. But where can I find this option when I embed the exported data.t3d into the Initialisation folder of a distribution and active the distribution by moving it into ext folder via ftp and then activate the extension in the extension manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While importing you have an option `force uids`. This will use the same uids as the export is done.  **But** that could destroy data on your importing installation if already data with those uids exist.

Therefore TYPO3 uses relocating on imports. Uids are adapted while imported to avoid collision or overwriting.

TYPO3 tries to identify all uids but sometimes (fields not clearly defines as page uids, usage in typoscript, ...) it fails and you need to adapt the uids by hand.

Be aware that `force uids` is used for all uids not only `pages` records.

If you import into a blank installation the pages are generated in order of occurence in the import. This will be the same order if you install an export of an once imported site (if you did not change pages meanwhile). Adding, deleting or moving pages in the second installation before the second export would result in changed uids in teh third installation while importing.

Comment: Ah ok. Good to know. In the above case I imported it into blank sites. So in case of already existing uids its kind of sensitive. But where can I find this option when I embed the exported data.t3d into the Initialisation folder of a distribution and active the distribution by moving it into ext via ftp and activate the extension in the extension manager? Similar like in this tutorial: https://jweiland.net/video-anleitungen/typo3/typo3-projekte-verwalten/templates-als-distribution.html#c2754

Comment: I have not build a distribution yet, so I don't know whether there is an option to force uids from inside an extension. But I would assume that you use/install a distribution in an empty installation.

Comment: Afaik it is not possible to force UIDs via the Initilisation folder of a distribution extension. The checkbox to force UIDs is only part of the import action of the impexp system extension.

Comment: it would be dangerous to force uids on importing data from a distribution. If there data already exists it would be overwritten.

Comment: Ah ok. Then I need to test the distribution and adjust the config setup (page ID conditions and stuff) if I make any changes in meantime. (Under the premise to active it on a blank site). Thanks for the inputs